# OCaml share structure between mli file and signature inside ml file

Tags: types, module, ocaml

The thing I'm ultimately trying to do is 1) restrict visibility into a module (hence the mli file) and 2) define a functor where the argument has a "canonical implementation" that lives in the source tree as an `ml`/`mli` pair and insists that arguments have the same shape as this canonical implementation.

Suppose I have a file `concat.ml` that contains a single function for string concatenation

```
(* concat.ml *)
type t = string
let concat x y = x ^ y
```

and I have an interface for it

```
(* concat.mli *)
type t
val concat : t -> t -> t
```

However, I also have a functor `join` that looks like this and expects something with the same shape as `Concat`. (The implementation of `join` is intentionally naive):

```
(* join.ml *)
module Join(X : Concat_type.TYPE) : sig
  val join : X.t list -> X.t
end = struct
  let rec join xs = match xs with
    | [] -> failwith "can't be empty"
    | [x] -> x
    | [x; y] -> X.concat x y
    | (x::xs') -> X.concat x (join xs')
end
```

In order to express the "same shape as Concat" constraint, I've had to make another `ml` file `concat_type.ml` that looks like this:

```
(* concat_type.ml *)
module type TYPE = sig
  type t
  val concat : t -> t -> t
end
```

`Concat_type.TYPE` and the `Concat` mli are nearly identical in this case. The only reason I made `concat_type.ml` at all was to support the functor `Join` and explicitly restrict what it can see if I try to apply it to a module mimicking the implementation of `concat`.

Is there a way to import `Concat_type.TYPE` into the `Concat` interface or vice versa or some other way to avoid duplication between them?

Comment: You should be able to just use `include Concat_type.TYPE` in concat.mli, I think

Comment: You can use `module type of Concat`, eg, `module Join (X : module type of Concat) : sig ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to express the `Concat` module interface via the `Concat_type.TYPE`  module type. It is also possible to get a module type of an existing module.

The first approach looks like this:

```
(* concat.mli *)
include Concat_type.TYPE
```

The second approach allows you to get rid of the `Concat_type`, though I personally dislike it, as I don't like the `module type of` construct. But still, there is a possibility:

```
module type Concat = module type of Concat

module Join (X : Concat) = struct 
  ...
end
```